# Getting Error:(55, 41) Kotlin: Type inference failed

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, intellij-idea, kotlin, spring-data

I get `Error:(55, 41) Kotlin: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is (Mutable)List<Optional<Address!>!>! but List<Address>? was expected`

I save the data to a mongoDB Document my build.gradle has:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin'
```

My Document Objects

```
@Document(collection = "address")
class Address {
    @Id
    var id: String? = null
    var number: String? = null
    var street: String? = null
    var neighborhood: String? = null
    var locality: String? = null
    var region: String? = null
    var country: String? = null
    var code: String? = null
    var google_place_id: String? = null

    constructor()
}
```

And

```
@Document(collection = "person")
class Person {
    @Id
    var id: String? = null
    var name: String? = null
    var lastName: String? = null
    var phone: String? = null
    var email: String? = null
    var password: String? = null
    @DBRef(db = "mlm")
    var address: List<Address>? = null

    constructor()
}
```

I have interfaces

```
@Repository
interface PersonRepository : MongoRepository<Person, String>
```

And

```
@Repository
interface AddressRepository : MongoRepository<Address, String>
```

My Controllers work
My Seeder / well test really to see how to do this looks like this and this is where I encounter the problem

```
class DbSeeder {
    @Autowired
    private val personRepository: PersonRepository? = null
    @Autowired
    private val addressRepository: AddressRepository? = null

    fun addressLoading() {
        val address1 = Address()
        address1.id = "5cb2e9424274072ec4bb4199"
        address1.number = "1"
        address1.street = "Microsoft Way"
        address1.neighborhood = "Redmond"
        address1.locality = "King County"
        address1.region = "Washington"
        address1.code = "425"
        address1.country = "United States"
        address1.google_place_id = "5644+83 Centurion"

        val address2 = Address()
        address2.id = "5cb2e9424274072ec4bb4198"
        address2.number = "1600"
        address2.street = "Amphitheatre Parkway"
        address2.neighborhood = ""
        address2.locality = "Mountain View"
        address2.region = "California"
        address2.country = "United States"
        address2.code = "94043"
        address2.google_place_id = "CWC8+Q9 Mountain View, California, USA"

        val address = Arrays.asList(address1, address2)
        this.addressRepository!!.insert(address)
    }

    fun personLoading() {
        val personDocument = Person()
        personDocument.id = "5cb2e9424274072ec4bb4197"
        personDocument.name = "William"
        personDocument.lastName = "Gates"
        personDocument.phone = "1081010810"
        personDocument.email = "bill.gates@gmail.com"
        personDocument.password = "bill-secret"

        val personAddressDBRef = addressRepository!!.findById("5cb2e9424274072ec4bb4199")

        personDocument.address = Arrays.asList(personAddressDBRef)

    //  val personDBRef = personRepository!!.save(personDocument)  // If the ObjectID is requires else ware
        personRepository!!.save(personDocument)
    }
}
```

to save my address I need to find the Address related to the ObjectID then save the ObjectID as a DBRef in the person Document

```
val personAddressDBRef = addressRepository!!.findById("5cb2e9424274072ec4bb4199")
personDocument.address = Arrays.asList(personAddressDBRef) // << Error here
```

In the last line I get the error `Error:(55, 41) Kotlin: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is (Mutable)List<Optional<Address!>!>! but List<Address>? was expected`
**I seem to have no clue how to proceed**
I made it available on GitHub https://github.com/Morons/gofetchbyidandinsertdbref.git
Any help will be apreciated

Comment: The errors displayed here comes from the logs, No mistake there
@yole You have a solution rather?

Comment: The mistake was not showing the errors properly. Because they contained `<` and `>`, they need to be escaped by backticks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types to understand the way the inferred type is written. But the problem is simple enough:

1. `personAddressDBRef` has type `Optional<Address>` because that's what `findById` returns.
2. So `Arrays.asList(personAddressDBRef)` is `List<Optional<Address>>` (again, see the link above for why you see a more complicated type).
3. You can't set `personDocument.address` to a `List<Optional<Address>>`, you need a `List<Address>` instead.

So you need to decide how to convert an `Optional<Address>` to a `List<Address>`. One way would be

```
personDocument.address = personAddressDBRef.map { listOf(it) }.orElseGet { listOf() }
```

Comment: What causes `Type inference failed` error for Bundle parcelables?

Comment: Are you asking about some different code? There are no bundles or parcelables involved here.